# How to find and modify DOM nodes in the React before render?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, react-dom

i cound't see right way how to find and modify React DOM nodes before render.
For example i need to make all founded images inside component as **lazy load**. But the problem is that I don't know which nodes will be inserted by the user. Therefore, I need to look for them after the user places nodes in the component, by using `componentWillMount` or `constructor` i think...

Actually in jQuery, to replace real src after user insereted it in. I will do something like this:

```
jQuery('.wrapper img').each(element => {
    let realSrc = element.attr('src')
    element
        .attr('data-real-src', realSrc)
        .attr('src', './fakeimage.png')
})
```

So in the React,  i have to do something like this i think...

```
const modifiedChildren = children.reduce((arr, next) => {
    let modified = {
        ...next,
        src: './fakeimage.png',
        'data-real-src': next.src
    }
    return [
        ...arr,
        modified
    ]
}, [])

render {
    <div className="wrapper">{ modifiedChildren }</div>
}
```

Can you navigate me some please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop thinking in DOM nodes. Start thinking in components.

You want a new component `LazyLoadedImage` which gets the real URL and displays it after some trigger. Something like that:

```
import fakeImage from 'assets/fakeimage.png';

const LazyLoadedImage = ({url, displayActualImage, ...props}) => {
    if(displayActualImage) return <img {...props} src={url}>;
    else return <img {...props} src={fakeImage}>;
}
```

Usage example:

```
<Slider>
    {images.map((obj, index) =>
     <LazyLoadedImage className='slider__img' url={obj.largeImageURL}
                      alt={obj.tags || 'cap'} key={index}/>)}
</Slider>
```

Comment: But actually i could't find right way how to recursively search for <img> in the DOM that the user posted. Because he could insert defferent DOM in component

Comment: You need to show more information. The user usually can't insert "DOM nodes" into an application. You don't need to search for <img> in DOM. If you think that, you are completely thinking in the wrong direction. Think about data and components, NOT about DOM nodes

Comment: So user just put it in. Then i can work only with `this.props.children` array of objects

Comment: See update. Users don't put in `<img>` tags, they input URLs, Tags etc. *Get your head away from DOM nodes!*

Comment: Recursivley search and replace in `this.props.children` array seems really difficult work =(

Comment: Stop that. It's nonsense. Read *and understand* what I am writing

Comment: I think I understand you. It is necessary to force the user to use a lazy wrapper for images if he wants to achieve a lazy loading effect. This seems like the easiest way. Thanks you!